# How to convert an image to Base64 encoding

Tags: php, image, base64

How can I convert an image from a URL to Base64 encoding?

Comment: What do you want to do this for?

Comment: to embed it in src attribute of Img tag

Comment: This is an old thread, but for completeness' sake:

It makes a lot of sense to encode images, especially small ones (under 1k), for use in css. This way you save one request, which would take longer and might be even larger, due to overhead.

Answer (score 742, accepted):

I think that it should be:

```
$path = 'myfolder/myimage.png';
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
```

Comment: It depends on what you need the image for. If it's as an inline URL, this is the way to go. It's not identical with mere base64 encoding though.

Comment: Excellent tip, now i will create be a function to edit file upload, or a revert move_uploaded_file(), thanks

Comment: This worked like a charm! Been stuck with DomPDF image for a while now, thank you so  much for this!

Comment: The `pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)` part might not work with **SVG** images. Just change the last line to 
```php
$base64 = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' . base64_encode($data);
```

Comment: You should use mime_content_type() to get mimetype instead of extension (not reliable)

Comment: @EddieC. - Good tip regards SVG.  Would it be more robust if the script queried the mimetype rather then the extension?

Comment: $type = \Illuminate\Support\Str::of($path)->explode('.')->last()

Answer (score 147):

Easy:

```
$imagedata = file_get_contents("/path/to/image.jpg");
             // alternatively specify an URL, if PHP settings allow
$base64 = base64_encode($imagedata);
```

Bear in mind that this will enlarge the data by 33%,
and you'll have problems with files whose size exceed your `memory_limit`.

Comment: @anna it does! Base64 encoding will generally do that.

Comment: It seems to return the image in base64 but not the header (`data:image/type;base64,`), so the image won't display with this code alone.

Answer (score 48):

Also use this way to represent an image in Base64-encoded format...

Find the PHP function `file_get_content` and next use the function `base64_encode`.

And get the result to prepare str as `data:" . file_mime_type . " base64_encoded string`. Use it in the `img` `src` attribute. The following code ma be helpful:

```
// A few settings
$img_file = 'raju.jpg';

// Read image path, convert to base64 encoding
$imgData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($img_file));

// Format the image SRC:  data:{mime};base64,{data};
$src = 'data: '.mime_content_type($img_file).';base64,'.$imgData;

// Echo out a sample image
echo '<img src="'.$src.'">';
```

Comment: If failed to find function mime_content_type just add the function from svogal from http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php

Answer (score 20):

Just in case you are (for whatever reason) unable to use `curl` nor `file_get_contents`, you can work around:

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng('...');
ob_start();
imagepng($img);
$bin = ob_get_clean();
$b64 = base64_encode($bin);
```

Answer (score 16):

Very simple and to be commonly used:

```php
function getDataURI($imagePath) {
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $type = $finfo->file($imagePath);
    return 'data:' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents($imagePath));
}

// Use the above function like below:
echo '<img src="' . getDataURI('./images/my-file.svg') . '" alt="">';
echo '<img src="' . getDataURI('./images/my-file.png') . '" alt="">';
```

Note: The MIME type of the file will be added automatically (taking help from [this PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php)).

Answer (score 14):

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode(file_get_contents("IMAGE URL HERE")) ?>">
```

I was trying to use this resource, but I kept getting an error. I found the code above worked perfectly.

I just replaced "IMAGE URL HERE" with the URL of your image - http://www.website.com/image.jpg

Comment: This is worthful

Comment: if use 'image/png' this , then only jpg image wokrs, png not works

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code for uploading to encode and save it to a MySQL database:

```
if (!isset($_GET["getfile"])) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    } else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

        $bin_string = file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $hex_string = base64_encode($bin_string);
        $mysqli = mysqli_init();

        if (!$mysqli->real_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'arihant')) {
            die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO upload(image) VALUES ('" . $hex_string . "')");
    }
}
```

For showing the image, use this:

```
echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64, $image' width=300>";
```

Comment: This wasn't asked for.

Comment: why specific image/jpeg?

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this via [cURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL). You just need a path to an image file and pass it to the function given below...

```
public static function getImageDataFromUrl($url)
{
    $urlParts = pathinfo($url);
    $extension = $urlParts['extension'];
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $base64 = 'data:image/' . $extension . ';base64,' . base64_encode($response);
    return $base64;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using a [cURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) call... This is better than the **file_get_contents()** function. Of course, use **base64_encode()**.

```
<?php
    $url = "http://example.com";

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
?>

<img src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($output);?>">
```

Comment: `curl` is absolutely not "better" than `file_get_contents` unless you need to add additional data to the call ex. authentication.
Moreover, `file_get_contents` is gonna fallback to getting a local file's contents when possible, thus not making a useless network call.