# PHP convert an image made in the file into base64

Tags: php, base64

I have an image that I  have created by combining images based on database data, and was wondering hw to convert that to base 64. I tried this but the characters returned can not be decoded into an image:

```
$encode ="data:image/png"; 
imagepng($image);
echo (base64_encode($encode));
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967515/convert-image-to-base64-encoding-in-php) among others but that requires a path that I don't have. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following will allow you to get the image data without having to create a temporary file (I've had nightmares with temporary files before when too many users were online...)

```
ob_start(function($c) {return "data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode($c);});
imagepng($image);
ob_end_flush();
```

This will output something similar to:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQAgMAAABinRfyAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAAxQTFRFAGVygICA/8wz/+aZTn6FEAAAAAF0Uk5TAEDm2GYAAAABYktHRACIBR1IAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH2wkZEwoSgxq4wwAAAB1pVFh0Q29tbWVudAAAAAAAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIEdJTVBkLmUHAAAAS0lEQVQI1w3EMQ3AMAwEwMdTEmWRSF68h0RQBIKl5vkUirdGX99wuKUPKkjJkfM4jueE+ivo7VW6wDCCq1VtEdtiIMY2BGlgwUU+P38ZK+RwskeQAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
```

Which is suitable for use inside an `<img src="..." />`.

#### Edit For PHP < 5.3 without anonymous functions:

```
// Define the function first
function ob_base64_encode($c) {
  return "data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode($c);
}
// And pass its name as a string
ob_start('ob_base64_encode');
imagepng($image);
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: This gives me an error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')'

Comment: @jersam515 You must have a PHP version older than 5.3 so the anonymous function is not permitted.  Define the function with a name and pass the string name as a callback.

Comment: @Kolink, hope you don't mind the edit. This was a good answer and I want to make it work for the OP.

Comment: @Michael - Thanks, I guess I'm just used to having control over what PHP version I use XD At least I haven't used `[...]` array syntax or array dereferencing in an answer yet :p

Comment: @Kolink <3 array literals and function dereferencing in 5.4 <3 <3 <3

Comment: @Michael And the build-in development server! I didn't want to install a full production server just to test on, so I had made my own server in PHP but it was kinda buggy. This new stuff is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You are encoding the string "data:image/png" - naturally you won't be able to decode it into an image.  Assuming `$image` contains valid image data, you should be able to simply do

```
imagepng($image, $temp_file_name);
base64_encode(file_get_contents($temp_file_name));
```

Answer (score 0):

**from manuals:** http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php#105200

```
/**
 * Returns base64 encoded string prepended by "data:image/"
 *
 * @param $filename string
 * @param $filetype string 
 * @return string
 */
 function base64_encode_image($filename=string, $filetype=string)
 {
     if ($filename) {
         $imgbinary = fread(fopen($filename, "r"), filesize($filename));
             return 'data:image/' . $filetype 
                    . ';base64,' . base64_encode($imgbinary);
    }
}
```

Function code by luke at lukeoliff.com.

Function comments by [me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4001329/eric-ruiz).