# How to identify image traffic from other websites' url?

Tags: web-traffic

Isn't browser actually fetch the images?

If I put some image url of other website in my blog, these website might ban the image traffic from my blog. How could they identify it's outside? Just by url? But it's same as url on their own websites.

Comment: Most browsers sent the http referer (sic!) header, it contains the URL where you came from (i.e., where hte image was embedded). - This is often used to check if it's a different domain and then block the request.

Comment: Thanks! I guessed so. Lazy to verify. Annoying! Cheap!

Comment: I just added an "official" answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers sent the HTTP referer (sic!) header, it contains the URL where you came from (i.e., where the image was embedded). - This is often used to check if it's a different domain and then block the request.

See [PHP code for anti hotlinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895557/php-code-for-anti-hotlinking) for other strategies for hot linking protection.