# PHP disable access from other sites

Tags: php, hotlinking

How can i make this file to redirect or to block if visited from another site.

example i want to allow this script to be accessed just from my site example.com and if any other site try to access this php file can it be blocked or redirect

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {


    require_once './include/db.php';
    require_once './include/video-stream.php';
    $stm = $db->prepare("select * from video where code=?");
    $stm->execute(array($_GET['id']));

    if ($stm->rowCount() > 0) {

        $row = $stm->fetch();


        $stream = new VideoStream($row->path);
        $stream->start();
    } else {
        header("message1");
        echo "message2";
        die();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the referrer and check if the URL is referred from your website. $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];

Comment: if (isset($_SERVER['REFERER']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {

u think this?

Comment: `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` isn't reliable; read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6023980/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165975/determining-referer-in-php

Comment: `stripos()` can achieve this.

Comment: What about using .htaccess/nginx rules to achieve this?http://nginxlibrary.com/hotlink-protection/ https://perishablepress.com/creating-the-ultimate-htaccess-anti-hotlinking-strategy/

Comment: this is php file and not a jpg,gif, or png file

Comment: As @Fred-ii- mentioned, referrer is not really reliable, and can be spoofed . You could still use it depending on how much of a security you would like, but if you really would like it to be secure you can use WP nonce logic; https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895557/php-code-for-anti-hotlinking

Comment: `if($host=="www.example.com"){...}` and using an added *twist* ;-) There, *"done like dinner"*. I'll let you figure out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Create a .htaccess file in that directory where the file resides and add

```
<Files "*">
 Order deny, allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from .example.com
</Files>
```

which will block that directory accessing from other sites

Comment: i use this
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .? - [F]

# The Friendly URLs part
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]



but how i can exclude folder a folder from here