# image to base64 string

Tags: php, html, string, image

i have uploaded an image into a folder called images ,now i have tried to convert the image into string but it does not work for me,here is my code ,can any one redirect me in the correct direction,i wanted to convert it into base64 string i have tried much with the code ,the images are now getting stored in the images folder.

```
<?php
//define a maxim size for the uploaded images in Kb
define ("MAX_SIZE","1000"); 

//This function reads the extension of the file. It is used to determine if the file    is an image by checking the extension.
function getExtension($str) {
$i = strrpos($str,".");
if (!$i) { return ""; }
$l = strlen($str) - $i;
$ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
return $ext;
}

//This variable is used as a flag. The value is initialized with 0 (meaning no error  found)  
//and it will be changed to 1 if an errro occures.  
//If the error occures the file will not be uploaded.
$errors=0;
//checks if the form has been submitted
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) 
{
//reads the name of the file the user submitted for uploading
$image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
//if it is not empty
if ($image) 
{
//get the original name of the file from the clients machine
$filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
//get the extension of the file in a lower case format
$extension = getExtension($filename);
$extension = strtolower($extension);
//if it is not a known extension, we will suppose it is an error and will not  upload the file,  
//otherwise we will do more tests
if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") &&  ($extension != "gif")) 
{
 //print error message
 echo '<h1>Unknown extension!</h1>';
 $errors=1;
 }
 else
 {
 //get the size of the image in bytes
 //$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] is the temporary filename of the file
 //in which the uploaded file was stored on the server
 $size=filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

 //compare the size with the maxim size we defined and print error if bigger
 if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
 {
 echo '<h1>You have exceeded the size limit!</h1>';
 $errors=1;
 }

//we will give an unique name, for example the time in unix time format
$image_name=time().'.'.$extension;
//the new name will be containing the full path where will be stored (images folder)
$newname="images/".$image_name;
//we verify if the image has been uploaded, and print error instead
$copied = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);
if (!$copied) 
{
echo '<h1>Copy unsuccessfull!</h1>';
$errors=1;
}}}}

 //If no errors registred, print the success message
 if(isset($_POST['Submit']) && !$errors) 
 {
 echo "<h1>File Uploaded Successfully! Try again!</h1>";
 function encode_img($image_name)
 {
 $fd = fopen ($image_name, 'rb');
 $size=filesize ($image_name);
 $cont = fread ($fd, $size);
 fclose ($fd);
 $encimg = base64_encode($cont);
 return $encimg;
 } 
 $image_base64=encode_img('$image_name'); 
 echo $image_base64;// to encode the image 
 }
 ?>
 <!--next comes the form, you must set the enctype to "multipart/frm-data" and use an input type "file" -->
 <form name="newad" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="">
 <table>
 <tr><td><input type="file" name="image"></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Upload image"></td></tr>
 </table>   
 </form>
```

Comment: Take a look at the question posted here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967515/convert-image-to-base64-encoding-in-php

Answer (score 0):

simple use file_get_contents

```
$contents = file_get_contents('path to your image');
$encode   = base64_encode($contents);
```

Comment: i have edited my code ,after this code of line $newname="images/".$image_name; then i have added echo $newname; $contents = file_get_contents('$newname');
$encode   = base64_encode($contents); echo $encode;i can print the image path but i didnt got the string ?why is it so?

Comment: first of all check $newname returns correct image name or not

Comment: check this out http://codepad.viper-7.com/2ysGq3.. The only thing I can say is path to file for file_get_contents() is not correct.

Comment: yes it is returning the correct path,i have uploade apply.png but it is stored as 543654.png in the images folder,i have got the image path as images/543654.png

Comment: what are you passing to file_get_contents()..?

Comment: I cannt see any error then .. you are getting correct image when you echo $contents .. right ..?