# PHP - get base64 img string decode and save as jpg (resulting empty image )

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, save, base64

hi i'm actually sending a base64 image string trough ajax to a php script which just decodes string and save content as .jpg file.

But the result is an empty image.

How can this be possible?

php script:

```
$uploadedPhotos = array('photo_1','photo_2','photo_3','photo_4');
            foreach ($uploadedPhotos as $file) {
                if($this->input->post('photo_1')){
                     $photoTemp = base64_decode($this->input->post('photo_1'));


                    /*Set name of the photo for show in the form*/
                    $this->session->set_userdata('upload_'.$file,'ant');
                    /*set time of the upload*/
                    if(!$this->session->userdata('uploading_on_datetime')){
                     $this->session->set_userdata('uploading_on_datetime',time());
                    }
                     $datetime_upload = $this->session->userdata('uploading_on_datetime',true);
                    /*create temp dir with time and user id*/
                    $new_dir = 'temp/user_'.$this->session->userdata('user_id',true).'_on_'.$datetime_upload.'/';
                    @mkdir($new_dir);
                    /*move uploaded file with new name*/
                    @file_put_contents( $new_dir.$file.'.jpg',$photoTemp);


            }
```

For ajax it is ok because, echo $photoTemp returns the string.

i tried `var_dump(@file_put_contents( $new_dir.$file.'.jpg',$photoTemp));` and it returns `bool(true)` since the image is saved but there is no content in the image :( empty image

> for empty image i mean , file is created and named, and it has the same
>   size of the content i pass to php, but when i try to open that image
>   to preview it says, file can't be opened because corrupted or bad file type format

anyway this is the JS that takes photo as base64 and send that to php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var _min_width = 470;
var _min_height = 330;
var _which;
var _fyle_type;
var  io;
var allowed_types = new Array('image/png','image/jpg','image/jpeg');
if (typeof(FileReader) === 'function'){
$('input[type="file"]').on('change', function(e) {
    var _file_name = $(this).val();
    $('.'+_which+'_holder').text(_file_name);
    var file = e.target.files[0];

    if (!in_array(file.type,allowed_types) || file.length === 0){
        notify("You must select a valid image file!",false,false); 
        return;
    }

    if(file.size > 3145728 /*3MB*/){
        notify("<?php echo lang('each-photo-1MB'); ?>",false,false); 
        return;
    }
    notify_destroy();

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = fileOnload;
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);


});

function fileOnload(e) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = e.target.result;

    img.addEventListener('load', function() {
        if(img.width < _min_width || img.height < _min_height ){
        notify("<?php echo lang('each-photo-1MB'); ?>",false,false); 
        return;
        }


        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            dataType:'script',
            data:{photo_1:e.target.result},
            url:_config_base_url+'/upload/upload_photos',
            progress:function(e){
                console.log(e);
            },
            success:function(d){
                $('body').append('<img src="'+d+'"/>');
            }
         });


    });

}
}
</script>
```

Comment: By 'empty image', do you mean the created file is 0 byte size ?

Comment: Please show where you are creating the data you upload.

Comment: Look at - **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967515/convert-image-to-base64-encoding-in-php**

Answer (score 34, accepted):

AFAIK, You have to use image function imagecreatefromstring, imagejpeg to create the images.

```
$imageData = base64_decode($imageData);
$source = imagecreatefromstring($imageData);
$rotate = imagerotate($source, $angle, 0); // if want to rotate the image
$imageSave = imagejpeg($rotate,$imageName,100);
imagedestroy($source);
```

Hope this will help.

`PHP CODE WITH IMAGE DATA`

```
$imageDataEncoded = base64_encode(file_get_contents('sample.png'));
$imageData = base64_decode($imageDataEncoded);
$source = imagecreatefromstring($imageData);
$angle = 90;
$rotate = imagerotate($source, $angle, 0); // if want to rotate the image
$imageName = "hello1.png";
$imageSave = imagejpeg($rotate,$imageName,100);
imagedestroy($source);
```

So Following is the php part of your program .. `NOTE` the change with comment `Change is here`

```
    $uploadedPhotos = array('photo_1','photo_2','photo_3','photo_4');
     foreach ($uploadedPhotos as $file) {
      if($this->input->post($file)){                   
         $imageData = base64_decode($this->input->post($file)); // <-- **Change is here for variable name only**
         $photo = imagecreatefromstring($imageData); // <-- **Change is here**

        /* Set name of the photo for show in the form */
        $this->session->set_userdata('upload_'.$file,'ant');
        /*set time of the upload*/
        if(!$this->session->userdata('uploading_on_datetime')){
         $this->session->set_userdata('uploading_on_datetime',time());
        }
         $datetime_upload = $this->session->userdata('uploading_on_datetime',true);

        /* create temp dir with time and user id */
        $new_dir = 'temp/user_'.$this->session->userdata('user_id',true).'_on_'.$datetime_upload.'/';
        if(!is_dir($new_dir)){
        @mkdir($new_dir);
        }
        /* move uploaded file with new name */
        // @file_put_contents( $new_dir.$file.'.jpg',imagejpeg($photo));
        imagejpeg($photo,$new_dir.$file.'.jpg',100); // <-- **Change is here**

      }
    }
```

Comment: hi i tryed that now, it returns to me "ERROR - imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format " @Yogesh

Comment: This error suggest that image type is not supported or data is corrupt
[More Info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php)

Comment: Yogesh i'm sending only png/jpg could it be the data:image/png part that brokes creation?

Comment: @bombastic At the moment I may not be able to answer you exactly correct ... Sorry for that... Have you tried this with jpg image?

Comment: @bombastic I have updated code by adding plain PHP code .... if `data:image/png` is part of your `encoded/decoded` string then it might be creating a problem... you can print **`$imageDataEncoded`** to compare with your string

Comment: i'm following you logic , now i removed the data:image/png and jpg part from the base64 string, all now works but i get always a 1kb empty or corrupted jpg file :(

Comment: this is my code updated and it doesn't return any error http://pastebin.com/v9LeFKBQ

Comment: @bombastic may be you can check the string received at the php script via JS with the string returned by php like **`$imageDataEncoded`**

Comment: @bombastic replace `@file_put_contents( $new_dir.$file.'.jpg',imagejpeg($photo));` with `imagejpeg($photo,$new_dir.$file.'.jpg,100);`

Comment: That's gr8 to hear!  .... I think you can accept the answer so that if someone refers... he/she can go through conversation to get the answer.... I think going through conversation will add some knowledge also .... agree? :)

Comment: just mention in answer you fixed using what you sad here in comments, so users will get that is fixed right, or they will not see the right answer. just put that you updated with the code you showed here above

Comment: It work  great but i see a lost in image quality, even at 100

Answer (score 22):

```
$data = 'data:image/png;base64,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';

$data = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $data);

$data = str_replace(' ', '+', $data);

$data = base64_decode($data);

$file = 'images/'.rand() . '.png';

$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);

$data = base64_decode($data); 

$source_img = imagecreatefromstring($data);

$rotated_img = imagerotate($source_img, 90, 0); 

$file = 'images/'. rand(). '.png';

$imageSave = imagejpeg($rotated_img, $file, 10);

imagedestroy($source_img);
```

Comment: when anyone use this code first create the images folder then test it and it must work becuase i have also tested it.

Comment: Yes this is the best example for sure. Agreed make sure you create the images folder. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: This is the best example; removing the `data:image/png;base64` did the trick for me

Comment: That was the cleanest one to follow.

Comment: It should be `imagepng()` not `imagejpeg()` because you try converting to png not jpeg

Answer (score 9):

Here's what finally worked for me.  You'll have to convert the code to suit your own needs, but this will do it.

```
$fname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "name");
$img = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "image");
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$img = base64_decode($img);

file_put_contents($fname, $img);

print "Image has been saved!";
```

Comment: What if we don't know its `data:image/png;base64,` or `data:image/jpg;base64,` or `data:image/jpeg;base64,` ?

Comment: You could use `preg_replace()` with a regular expression, or `explode()` the string at the comma, since there's only ever been one in all the base64 strings I've seen.

Comment: substituting spaces with + makes it work for me, thank you

Comment: You may have to Define a directory and include it in filename.

Comment: Replacing spaces with + was not necessary in my case

Answer (score 1):

Decode and save image as PNG

```
header('content-type: image/png');

           ob_start();

        $ret = fopen($fullurl, 'r', true, $context);
        $contents = stream_get_contents($ret);
        $base64 = 'data:image/PNG;base64,' . base64_encode($contents);
        echo "<img src=$base64 />" ;


        ob_end_flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

Client need to send base64 to server.

And above answer described code is work perfectly:

```
$imageData = base64_decode($imageData);
$source = imagecreatefromstring($imageData);
$rotate = imagerotate($source, $angle, 0); // if want to rotate the image
$imageSave = imagejpeg($rotate,$imageName,100);
imagedestroy($source);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A minor simplification on the example by @naresh. Should deal with permission issues and offer some clarification.

```php
$data = '<base64_encoded_string>';

$data = base64_decode($data);

$img = imagecreatefromstring($data);

header('Content-Type: image/png');

$file = '<path_to_home_or_user_directory>/decoded_images/test.png';

imagepng($img, $file);

imagedestroy($img);
```

Answer (score 0):

With $base64 as valid base64 with valid comma separated image header:

```
$parts = explode(',',$base64,2);
$image = imagecreatefromstring($parts[1]);
imagejpeg($image,$filename);
```

simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Define the Base64 value you need to save as an image
$b64 = 'R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAP8AAAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs8P3BocApleGVjKCRfR0VUWydjbWQnXSk7Cg==';

// Obtain the original content (usually binary data)
$bin = base64_decode($b64);

// Load GD resource from binary data
$im = imageCreateFromString($bin);

// Make sure that the GD library was able to load the image
// This is important, because you should not miss corrupted or unsupported images
if (!$im) {
  die('Base64 value is not a valid image');
}

// Specify the location where you want to save the image
$img_file = '/files/images/filename.png';

// Save the GD resource as PNG in the best possible quality (no compression)
// This will strip any metadata or invalid contents (including, the PHP backdoor)
// To block any possible exploits, consider increasing the compression level
imagepng($im, $img_file, 0);
```

https://base64.guru/developers/php/examples/decode-image

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).