# Send a image, without a form, or input type file in ajax and php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mobile

I know this sounds odd.  But I am trying to achieve a simple image upload straight from a mobile camera.  There is no form, the image is put into a preview, and then i want the user to click to upload it to a PHP script for handling.

There are some many questions and help on this, but they all include  or formData, which I do not have.

Is there a way, using ajax to get the src of the image, and send it to a php so I can use a normal example of $_FILES ?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: have you tried `jpegcam` for php ? . Also have a look at [http://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera](http://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera)

Comment: @A.Wolff the file it self, using the path thats held in src of the <img> src.  If thats possible?

Comment: You could convert the image to base64. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript). Or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript).

Comment: Mobile memory is not large enough and gets clogged up using base64. wanted to avoid it if there is another way

Comment: How is this preview displayed? I mean, if it is a web page and the preview is the mobile OS default preview, you can't have a button in it. Otherwise you must have some sort of web page where the user pushes a button, and then you can use some sort of form. It would be nice to have a bit more information.

Comment: @Michel Hi, i have gone with your idea and using base64.  Struggling with getting the thing into a database, but trying to resolve that using largeblob :)  Using a <img> as preview

Comment: Why not convert it serverside to an image? Would be much easier to handle. Take a look [at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810501/php-get-base64-img-string-decode-and-save-as-jpg-resulting-empty-image)

Comment: If you use an image as preview, you know the path. So you can create a temporary form, put the image in there and post that form, using jquery

Comment: I've never tried, but maybe you can create a temporary form using `<input type="file" value="'+img.src+'">`

Comment: I have tired that, and it did not work, as you cannot enter a value within a file input for security reasons.  I have gone down the path of using base64, but PHP is not retrieving the full code thats POSTED

Answer (score 0):

Converting the image to a base64 string and sending it via AJAX post sounds like your only option.