# How to post a base64 encoded image as a file asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My API requires an image to be posted to it as a file. Currently, I have an image in base64 format that is generated by a custom image creator.

I understand that if my form had a basic `input` with the `type` of `file` I could use `new FormData()` and then do something along the lines of `formData.append('file', myFile)`.

How can I post this base64 encoded image as an image file to my API via jQuery asynchronously?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upload a base64 encoded image using FormData?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667820/upload-a-base64-encoded-image-using-formdata)

Answer (score -1):

Before appending your base64 file, convert it into an image file as

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...'; //put your base64 image here
```

Now append this image as

```
formData.append('file', image);
```