# convert html image to base64

Tags: php, image, base64

i have application to send email. library used swift mailer.
i have generated html string for sending email 
which contains various tag including  tag 
can i convert that img src tag to bas64 image

for ex

```
   <html>
some txt+html ...
<img src="some-path/image.jpg">
some text+html ..
</html>
```

to

```
  <html>
    some txt+html ...
    <img src="data:image/jpg;base64, $base64_code_of_image.jpg ">
    some text+html ..
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. You just have to convert the image in base64 using base64_encode() function.

```
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
```

[How to convert an image to base64 encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967515/convert-image-to-base64-encoding-in-php)

Comment: input will be html string which contains image path, dont know thier position, then how to do