# embedded image in svg disappear on converting svg to png

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick

Please help. I was using php Imagick library to successfully convert svg (including embedded png image in `<image/>` tag) to png image till recently. I guess after a few updates on ubuntu the embedded png image stopped appearing in the converted image from svg.

```
$svg =  json_decode($_POST['svgdata']);
$svg = '<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>'.$svg;
$im = new Imagick();
$success = $im->readImageBlob($svg);
$im->setImageFormat("png24");
$im->writeImage('png_img/var.png');
```

If I echo $svg it gives me a correct image. [image: output of echo $svg;]

whereas the saved image is[image].

For reference:

```
$svg = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; -moz-user-select: text;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="794" version="1.1" height="122">
<image class="barcode" style="-moz-user-select: text;" xlink:href="images/52aab69d.png" preserveAspectRatio="none" height="40" width="266" y="30" x="380"></image>
<rect class="ref" style="-moz-user-select: text;" stroke="#000" fill="#000000" ry="0" rx="0" r="0" height="18" width="18" y="15" x="10"></rect></svg>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to do it in a totally different way. I took help from -> [converting image to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967515/convert-image-to-base64-encoding-in-php).

Now that the image has been embedded in the SVG the php code successfully converts the svg to PNG image. Just replaced the image path with base64 string.

Comment: Thanks! I had the exact same problem. After moving to another host/server embedded img disappeared :( Your solution works though :) Did you ever found out what caused this? Thanks again for posting your answer!

Comment: I never could find out what caused it. If I were to guess, it may be upgraded security level in library, disallowing external constituents.

Comment: Yeah, some kind of security problem i guess. Your fix makes it work though :)

Answer (score 1):

The `xlink:href` should be a full qualified domain name. The relative path "images/52aab69d.png" will resolve through your web browser, but may not within the server path.

```xml
<image class="barcode" 
       style="-moz-user-select: text;" 
       xlink:href="http://localhost/images/52aab69d.png" 
       preserveAspectRatio="none" 
       height="40" width="266"
       y="30" x="380"></image>
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but I tried giving the complete path in image, it just doesn't work. I get exactly the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The interesting workaround found by Puneet doesn't really solve the problem mentioned:

1. let's have an svg **A** embedded into another svg file **B.svg**
2. convert **B** into another format - let's say png- using Imagick
3. **A** is not processed and not shown in the converted file **B.png**

This is a problem, expecially if your purpose is slightly different: for example if you **need** to convert your SVG into a PostScript file in order to send it to a printer, the solution mentioned by Puneet doesn't work.

Lets analyze the problem:

Imagick doesn't convert **just** the embedded svg.
I tried using Gmagick, another library used by big companies. No way.

I tried using the "convert" command line tool (I'm in a Debian 8 environment).

```
convert withNestedSvgTag.svg withNestedSvgTag.ps
```

No way.

It seems that the parser that parses the SVG file ignores completely the nested `<svg>` tags, accepting only the root `<svg>` tag.

I have another server, (Debian 7 and Imagick 3.1.0RC1), and it works like a sharm.

The other server seems rendering recursively each svg nested tag.

This means that the problem isn't the SVG file or the PHP code (consider that the [Imagick class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) library simply wraps [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)).

So, in conclusion, the real solutions are:

1.1 - Amend the Imagemagick code (I'll write to the community of developers reporting the problem  in the bug section)

1.2 - Substituting the  tag with another one, like the  tag.

The 1.2 is another workaround, I know, but it seems working, obviously you have to set up properly the size of the elements in the group tag.