# How to upload images in jaggeryjs?

Tags: jaggery-js

**This is my sample HTML code**

```
<html>
        <head>
            <title>
                fileupload
            </title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="process.jag" method="post" id="" name="">
                  <!-- File input filed -->
                  <input type="file" name="myFile">

                  <!-- The submit button. It calls the server side function uploadfiles() on click -->
                  <input type="submit" id="" value="Upload File">

            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**This is my jaggery code**

```
<%
    var verb=request.getMethod();
    if (verb=='POST'){

        var log = new Log();
        var file = request.getFile("myFile");
        file.move("C:\Users\vatsal ramesh gosar\Desktop\New folder\form\fileUploadUsingJaggery"+file.getName());

        response.sendRedirect("https://www.google.com");

    }

%>
```

It is giving a NULL Pointer Exception.
Please help me solve this problem with an efficient code.

Answer (score 1):

`request.getFile("myFile")` does not represent a physical file, rather it represent a stream to the uploaded file. Hence you cannot "move" it using `file.move("/moving/path")` function. If you want to save the uploaded file, then use the following code snippet.

```
var uploadedFile = request.getFile("myFile");
var savedFile = new File("/path/to/save/location/" + uploadedFile.getName());
savedFile.open('w');
savedFile.write(uploadedFile.getStream());
savedFile.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Jaggery [documentation](http://jaggeryjs.org/documentation.jag?api=resource) I haven't find any way to upload image into the server. But some alternatives there...

You encode the image into base64 encoding, you may use this way too encode the images on [base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967515/how-to-convert-image-to-base64-encoding)

```
$path = 'myfolder/myimage.png';
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
```

then send the encoded String using [POST](http://jaggeryjs.org/documentation.jag?api=post) request using Jaggery.