# Access image which needs custom headers in php

Tags: php, image, email, header

I wanted to send an email with an image. I had used `<img src="urloftheimg" />`. But the image is not sending because to access this image we have to send custom headers. How do I send an image in the email which needs custom headers?

I am able to access the image somehow in the external PHP file with the following code:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
    $uri = 'http://urloftheimage';
    $ch = curl_init($uri);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER  => array('key:value'),
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  =>true,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE     => 1
    ));
    $out = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $out;
```

When I had `echo`, I got the image, but how do I send this image in the email?

Answer (score 0):

Send an email as HTML email and display image using base64

[How to convert image to base64 encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967515/how-to-convert-image-to-base64-encoding)

[Sending Nice HTML Email with PHP](https://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/)