# get image stored in database using fetch_object() PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have stored several images in mediumblob type on a SQL database , I have tired following code but it gives ASCII characters instead of images

```
    while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
      {
 echo ' <div class="col-md-3"> ';
 echo ' <h2>'.$obj->name.'</h2>';
 echo ' <img src=Image/'.$obj->pic.' />';
 echo ' <div class="row">'.$obj->price.'</div>';
 echo ' </div> ';
      }
```

how do I change this to appear an image?

```
echo ' <img src=Image/'.$obj->pic.' />';
```

I know it's not a good practice to store images inside databases.

Comment: Try inline base64 instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967515/how-to-convert-image-to-base64-encoding

Comment: It's exactly wrong. Look at this answer closely http://stackoverflow.com/a/18739753/3885509

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me !

```
  echo '<img src="data:image/x-icon;base64,'.base64_encode($obj->pic).'"> ';
```

Answer (score 0):

The format you would probably want to try is more like ( assuming the data in the `pic` column is already base64 encoded )

```
echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64, {$obj->pic}' /> ";
```

Comment: You could've just marked this question as duplicate, since it is an exact duplicate.