# Upload an image through HTTP POST with Postman

Tags: php, image, http, postman

I've been trying for a while to send an image via Postman to a simple PHP script that should display the sent image. The steps I followed were:

Postman "client" side:

1. Select *POST* request
2. Select HEADER *Content-Type* with value *multipart/form-data*
3. In the Body tab select *form-data* introduce the *key* = image_test, change from *Text* to *File* and search for a image, ex: photo.png
4. Send POST request.

In the PHP script I just have:
`echo '<img src="data:multipart/form-data,' . $_POST['image_test'] .'"/>';`

This solution isn't working for me although with `print_r($_POST)` I'm able to see the encoded image. Could this be a problem of the host (https://ide.c9.io) or Postman? I made some other tests with Postman and base64 images and the *Display* tab of Postman wasn't able to display the decoded images; the only way was to access through the browser.

Comment: I can understand that you are receiving the image on the server with print_r($_POST)?, so I guess postman is doing its job? What is that you see when using the print_r?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some code would help to understand what you are trying to do. You could try to send the image back to the client in base64 encoding. See [How to convert an image to base64 encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967515/how-to-convert-image-to-base64-encoding) for an example

Answer (score 1):

That link was useful to find the solution to this simple example. Basically the process to send data (in this case a image) from Postman is as follows:

1. Select POST request.
2. In body select form-data change type to file and enter a key for it.

The server will properly process it with a example like this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Receiving data with Postman</title>
    </head>

    <?php 
        $dir = '/';
        $file = basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $file)) {
            echo "Ok.\n";

        } else {
            echo "Error.\n";
        }
    ?>
    <img src="<?=$file?>"></img>

</html>
```