# Symfony 4 - API manage multiple files upload (no bundle)

Tags: api, symfony, multiple-file-upload

I'm building an API with Symfony 4 without API bundle. I'm creating all my endpoints manualy, everything is working fine.
My problem is when I'm trying to upload multiple files. 
I have an entity with a field pictures where I need the user to upload multiple files. 
The problem is that I can't get files, I only receive ONE file.

Here is the field on my entity, the is an array type, I don't know if this is the best pratice :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="array")
 * @OA\Property(type="array")
 * @Groups("main")
 */
private $pictures = [];
```

In my controller I'm trying to count files (only to test), but I always have 1 file :

```
$files = $request->files;
    return $this->json(count($files)); // result 1
```

The curl used to get this result :

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer MY_TOKEN" -F "pictures=@PATH_TO_FILE\4b737fac533294776e386a3469e84e16.png" -F "pictures=@PATH_TO_FILE\azekh1454621e54516ze321a511z6259.png" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/incidents/
```

add

I also tried with Postman, same result. This is my first API, I'm kinda lost !
I tried a LOT of thing, everything failed :(

Can anyone give me a clue to find the solution please ?

Thanks !!

Comment: php is designed that if your request has multiple assignments x='something' and x='else' it will be x='else' in the end and not x=['something', 'else']. the same applies to files. that's part 1 (the answer is, it must be `pictures[]=...`, possibly escaped, I don't remember ...) if that still doesn't help, have a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php and read carefully.

Comment: Well, thanks for this response, this is working if I add [] to my curl, but I don't know why this is not working in Postman. I though Postman can handle this kind of things :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like with any other request parameter provided, multiple instances of exactly the same parameter usually override each other:

`https://example.org/?param=1&param=2`

will be turned into

```
['param' => 2] // in $_REQUEST or whatever
```

so, sending two files with `pictures=...` will suffer the same fate.

to fix that problem, php *does* understand the `[]` syntax:

`https://example.org/?param[]=1&param[]=2`

will be turned into

```
['param' => [1,2]]
```

so, for curl it's sufficient to turn `pictures=...` into `pictures[]=...`.

Files can be transfered in different ways. PHP has a few pitfalls, for example, that it will only accept files when sent as `multipart/form-data` ([source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)) which leads to the postman problem, which apparently by default sends files differently and you have to set it differently, see the following SO question for some hints:

[Upload an image through HTTP POST with Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41790714/upload-an-image-through-http-post-with-postman)

Comment: Alright, that's working now, I added bracket to my curl to turn it into array :) Thank for your help !!