# Image nut Read in Php from database

Tags: php, database, image

I have this problem when I read a picture from the database.

It shows like this:

[image]

This my code:

```
<?php
include 'Header.php';
include 'yzd.php';
?>

<div class="container">
<h1> All Project </h1>
<?php
$posts = mysqli_query($db_connect,"select * from Project order by id desc");

while($post = mysqli_fetch_array($posts)){
    echo "
    <article>
    <a href='Project.php?id=$post[id]'>
    <h1>$post[NameProject]</h1>
    </a>
    <p class='text-muted']>
    <h3>$post[TypeProject]</h3>
    </p>
    <h4>$post[Description]</h4>

    $post[Pic];

    <p>-----------------------------------------------------------------------------</p>
    </article>";

}
?>
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: if you're going to post an image of code, don't expect much help

Comment: Hello! It seems as if your question is very poorly written. The way it is, it is only going to attract downvotes, and no answers.

Comment: dont store the actual image in the database, store its location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try converting the raw image output into a base 64 data URI [(see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967515/how-to-convert-image-to-base64-encoding)
you may be able to do this by changing

```
$post[Pic]
```

into

```
<img src='".'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($post["Pic"])."'/>
```

Given all of the images in your databases are stroed as png(s) The type may need to be varied dependent on image type.

Please in the future use code snippets and not screenshots.