# return response with json and image from controller

Tags: javascript, php, image, laravel, response

In my controller I am using imagemagick to manipulate user uploaded image, then I store it in the public folder.
The user sends the image along other data from a form.
What I want to do is send the data as json to the ajax request and I do it like this:

```
return response()->json($Model);
```

I also want to send the `$image` I created with imagemagick along the data so that I don't have to make a server call from the javascript to download the image again. I have it there so how can I send that too?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967515/how-to-convert-an-image-to-base64-encoding

Comment: I would guess an `echo` would work better than an `return`

Comment: @RiggsFolly like how? I converted the image to base64 and I am able to send it like this: `return response()->json(array('model' => $Model, 'image_for_preview' => $image_for_preview));` I mean, I tried `echo`, both send the data but what's the difference here?