# Postman upload file on API using raw

Tags: php, json, api

How do you upload a file on postman using raw mode.

I used a json entry like this:

```
{
    "inp_doc_uid": "750761691595cf3398da311004881705",
    "tas_uid": "71415152859433e07c33b11085554015",
    "app_doc_comment":"test upload",
    "form":"@/User/images.jpg"
}
```

the problem was the @ in php was deprecated and now recommended to use curlFile, how to do it in a json form?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are sending the image as part of the JSON, you would need to encode it. Base64 encoding is a good choice. On the server side, you will need to decode it as well.

See this answer to [How to convert an image to base64 encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3967527/336920):

```
$imagedata = file_get_contents("/path/to/image.jpg");
$base64 = base64_encode($imagedata);
```

Once you have the data, you can add it to the JSON:

```
{
    "inp_doc_uid": "750761691595cf3398da311004881705",
    "tas_uid": "71415152859433e07c33b11085554015",
    "app_doc_comment":"test upload",
    "form":"TWFuIGlzIGRpc3R..."
}
```

Also see [Base64 Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

Comment: Hi, How can you do  base64_ecode a file in postman? Can you give me a picture tutorial?

Comment: I don't think that Postman does the encoding if you send it as JSON, but you can use this site to encode it: https://www.base64encode.org/enc/

Comment: Thanks for your help mate. I appreciate it