# Send Images With Raw Option In Postman

Tags: image, post, postman

I'm trying to send a list of objects to my server with Postman. However, I can't find information about how to send images in Postman using the **Raw** option. I'm thinking of trying something like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "image1",
        "file": "(i don't know what to type here)"
    },
    {
        "name": "image2",
        "file": "(i don't know what to type here)"
    }
]
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a specific use case for uploading using **Raw**, then you can encode your images to base64 and send in JSON that way. See this answer for more info: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44929773/postman-upload-file-on-api-using-raw)

An easier way to do this is to use **form-data**, and select **File** instead of **Text**. Then, you can select 1 or more files to send in the body.

Postman docs for sending data: [Docs](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/requests/#sending-body-data)

[image: example]