# convert an image jpg to base 64 with php

Tags: php, wordpress, base64

I'm trying to convert an image on my wordpress blog to base64.

When I use [this website](https://www.base64-image.de/) to do it manually it works.

But when I try it in PHp it's not working:

```
$thePostThumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($postId, array(150,150));
background-image: url(\'data:image/jpg;base64,' . base64_encode($thePostThumb) . '\');
```

I have also tried this method:

```
$type = pathinfo(get_the_post_thumbnail_url($postId, array(150,150)), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents(get_the_post_thumbnail_url($postId, array(150,150));
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data)
```

I know the thumb img is being retrieved, just can't get it working.
Anyone know what might be going on.
I'm using xampp and developing on local machine

Comment: once try to provide hard-coded path in second code here:- `$data = file_get_contents(get_the_post_thumbnail_url($postId, array(150,150));` and then check it's working or not? May be folder permission restricts to get the image using file_get_contents (check folder have 077 permission or not)

Comment: Possible duplicates of:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13758760/4248328

Comment: @AlivetoDie Hi thanks for help, I'm using xampp and developing on local machine

Comment: what i said can you do that. also trun your debug mode on to see the possible errors. it's in `config.php`, trun debug mode on while doing what i suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This must be work, just tested locally:

```
$image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($postID, array(150,150));
$ext = pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
echo 'data:image/' . $ext . ';base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));
```

Comment: Thanks this works, something was not right with my code above. Not sure what though

Comment: Glad it's now working correctly, don't forget to update your question to solved.