# PHP - Echo an image as button

Tags: php, html, image

I'm just looking for little help to make the right code.

What i want.

```
echo "<a target='_blank' href='https://www.wbesite.kom". get_the_title() ."'>" IMAGE HERE "</a>";
```

This code doesn't work simply because I don't understand how to put image in `"IMAGE HERE"`.

Can someone help?

Comment: Image tag is ```img```. You are able to post it with ```src``` attribute as a direct link to it or as base64 encoded string if you don't want to reveal/create the link.

Comment: You mean like this <img src="https://imagelink.png"> but as you see i need the image to be in that specific place. And to put thsi code there just doesnt work.

Comment: @ANdy I think you got downvoted for lack of clarity. What is _"right way"_ of doing what??? Technically nothing wrong with your code. Nothing to fix. Is the title more correct about your issue, now?

Comment: is this wordpress related?

Comment: if you want to insert an image, there needs to be an `<img src=...>`.

Comment: ok, seeing the acceptance, am voting this as a typo, seeing it was just a missing dot.

Comment: M0ns1f solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the dot `.` operator before and after your `IMAGE HERE`.

Try this :

```
$imagehtml = '<img  src="path/to/image" />'; 
echo "<a target='_blank' href='https://www.wbesite.kom". get_the_title() ."'>". $imagehtml ."</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I put this together from this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967515/how-to-convert-an-image-to-base64-encoding) Perhaps it will work for you.

```
<?php

function get_the_title() {
echo "result of the get_the_title()";
}

// A few settings
$img_file = 'http://www.abarrak.com/public/icons/stackoverflow-icon.png';

// Read image path, convert to base64 encoding
$imgData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($img_file));

// Format the image SRC:  data:{mime};base64,{data};
$src = 'data: '. $img_file .';base64,'.$imgData;

// Echo out a sample image
$img =  '<img src="'.$src.'">';

echo "<a target='_blank' href='https://www.wbesite.kom". get_the_title() 
."'>" . $img .  "</a>";

?>
```