# How to convert image path to base64 encode data using PHP

Tags: php, base64

I need to convert the image URL to `base64_encode` data using PHP. I am explaining my code below.

```
<?php
$path='https://www.jquery-az.com/html/images/banana.jpg';
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64=base64_encode($data);
print_r($base64);exit;
?>
```

Here I am getting the blank output. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Enable the error logs. This path does not exist

Comment: I have changed the original path. In my case path is correct.

Comment: The above code returns the result in base64_encoding format. I don't get what's the error. Enable your error log. Blank page is never "blank" there are errors that are hidden there.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967515/how-to-convert-an-image-to-base64-encoding

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an image to base64 encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967515/how-to-convert-an-image-to-base64-encoding)

Answer (score 2):

your code is working for me. I suppose the error is that in php.ini is disallowed to open remote urls: http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen set it to `true`

add this line and check for error message

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$path='https://www.jquery-az.com/html/images/banana.jpg';
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64=base64_encode($data);
print_r($base64);exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's code to convert image to base64 format

```
        $path='http:\/\/abcd.com\/pub\/media\/catalog\/product\/\/m\/i\/mi-l32m5-ai.jpeg';
        $type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $data = file_get_contents($path);
        $base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
        echo $base64;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It will help you.

According to his question, he needs to encode the image path. First, check if the image exists, if yes then encode its path .

```
$path = 'your-file-path';
$file = 'your-file';
$image_with_path = $path.'/'.$file;
if(file_exists($image_with_path)){
    $base64 = base64_encode($image_with_path );
}
```

Comment: How will this code help? Please explain your answer

Comment: I would have thought that with 700+ Rep you would have understood the ability to **edit** your post and write a conherent and full answer in your post.....

Answer (score 0):

Please use the unescaped url in **$path** variable,

```
<?php    
$path='http://abcd.com/pub/media/catalog/product//m/i/mi-l32m5-ai.jpeg';
```