# How to upload blob with Bulletproof php

Tags: upload, blob, jpeg, bulletproof

I generate a blob jpeg in client side and need to send it to server using ajax and bulletproof php, is it possible without using database ?

Can i convert blob to a file client side so bulletproof can send it to server ?

Comment: Are you referring to the github.com/samayo/bulletproof library?

Comment: yes, thanks for this great library ! I need a secure image upload but i have blob, is there any way i can use bulletproof ?

Comment: Thanks. There are no functions in bulletproof to convert the image to blob type. I think you can find a script to get the blob, or try http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.readimageblob.php.  Since you mean blob as base64 you can search for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967515/how-to-convert-an-image-to-base64-encoding but there are no ways to get this using bulletproof. Or maybe use client-side languages like js to blob,it should be easy ... let me know if you have more questions