# Laravel Dompdf Set DPI removes image from pdf

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, email-attachments, dompdf

I am generating a PDF using `berryvdh/dompdf`, and sending it as an email attachment:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView($view, compact('******'));
$pdf->setOptions(['dpi' => 300 ]);
$output = $pdf->save('pdf/' . $name_pr);
```

In email function:

```
$message->attach($file, [
                        'as' => $reference.'.pdf',
                        'mime' => 'application/pdf',
                    ]);
```

And in my pdf view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{position: relative;}
        .pa{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 2;
            font-family:'Times New Roman';
            padding: 0 8px;
            font-size: 35px;
            height: 42px;
            /*        background: red    */

        }
        .ref-no{
            width: calc(23.6% - 16px);
            left: 31.3%;
            top: 13.01%;
        }
        .vrn{
            left: 31.3%;
            top: 14.9%;
            width: 22.8%;
        }
        .nop{
            left: 31.3%;
            top: 16.9%;
            width: 63.8%;
        }
        .nro{
            left: 31.3%;
            top: 18.9%;
            width: 63.8%;
        }
        .cn{
            left: 31.3%;
            top: 20.6%;
            width: 22.8%;
        }
        .add{
            left: 31.3%;
            top: 22.6%;
            width: 63.8%;
        }
        .pc{
            left: 31.3%;
            top: 24.6%;
            width: 22.8%;
        }
        .nic{
            left: 31.3%;
            top: 26.6%;
            width: 22.8%;
        }
        .en{
            left: 31.3%;
            top: 28.5%;
            width: 22.8%;
        }
        .ec{
            left: 31.3%;
            top: 30.3%;
            width: 22.8%;
        }
        .mm{
            left: 31.3%;
            top: 32.2%;
            width: 22.8%;
        }
        .dr{
            left: 31.3%;
            top: 34.1%;
            width: 22.8%;
        }
        .from-day{
            left: 36.5%;
            top: 37%;
            width: 4%;
            letter-spacing: 30px;
            padding-left: 20px;
        }
        .from-month{
            left: 43.5%;
            top: 37%;
            width: 4%;
            letter-spacing: 30px;
            padding-left: 20px;
        }
        .from-year{
            left: 50.5%;
            top: 37%;
            width: 9.5%;
            letter-spacing: 35px;
            padding-left: 20px;
        }

        .to-day{
            left: 65.6%;
            top: 37%;
            width: 4%;
            letter-spacing: 30px;
            padding-left: 20px;
        }
        .to-month{
            left: 72.7%;
            top: 37%;
            width: 4%;
            letter-spacing: 30px;
            padding-left: 20px;
        }
        .to-year{
            left: 79.7%;
            top: 37%;
            width: 9.5%;
            letter-spacing: 35px;
            padding-left: 20px;
        }
        .tc{
            left: 31.3%;
            top: 40.1%;
            width: 22.8%;
        }
        .sticker-sno {
            right: 11%;
            left: auto;
            top: 72.4%;
            height: 35px;
            font-size: 30px;
            width: 14%;
            padding-left: 10px;
        }
        .sticker-rno {
            left: auto;
            top: 73.8%;
            height: 35px;
            font-size: 30px;
            width: 23%;
            right: 10.6%;
        }
        .sticker-cno {
            left: auto;
            top: 75.1%;
            height: 35px;
            font-size: 30px;
            width: 23%;
            right: 10.6%;
        }
        .sticker-cp {
            left: auto;
            top: 76.3%;
            height: 35px;
            font-size: 30px;
            width: 23%;
            right: 10.6%;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <img src="{{asset('images/td.jpg')}}" alt="" style="width:100%">
    <div class="ref-no pa">155dds5544</div>
    <div class="vrn pa">A0E4974</div>
    <div class="nop pa">Abbas Abdulla</div>
    <div class="nro pa">Abbas Abdulla asas sadasd dasdsad</div>
    <div class="cn pa">9100074</div>
    <div class="add pa">157/85 A, Sassssss, asdawdw, wewdwds, sssdw</div>
    <div class="pc pa">2547852</div>
    <div class="nic pa">585441154311</div>
    <div class="en pa">84561215842131</div>
    <div class="ec pa">250cc</div>
    <div class="mm pa">TKS2587AS</div>
    <div class="dr pa">22/08/2016</div>

    <div class="from-day pa">14</div>
    <div class="from-month pa">08</div>
    <div class="from-year pa">2016</div>

    <div class="to-day pa">22</div>
    <div class="to-month pa">04</div>
    <div class="to-year pa">2025</div>

    <div class="tc pa">8049841564</div>

    <div class="sticker-sno pa">8049841564</div>
    <div class="sticker-rno pa">789456513</div>
    <div class="sticker-cno pa">548932115</div>
    <div class="sticker-cp pa">10 Years</div>

</body>

</html>
```

But when receiving the email the image is getting removed. And without  `$pdf->setOptions(['dpi' => 300 ]);` the **pdf** loads with image, but setup the pdf alignments i need this option enabled, is there anyway to overcome this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You can get all of the options like this: `dd($snappy->getOptions());` First check if pdf set options for dpi or not?

Comment: @HirenGohel i got the code from the dompdf documentation PDF::setOptions(['dpi' => 150]); and it works but the problem is the image disappears when i was enabled this option

Comment: Yes, they provided it in docs, use `php artisan vendor:publish` to create a config file located at `config/dompdf.php` which will allow you to define local configurations to change some settings (default paper etc). `dd($snappy->getOptions());` gives you options that you have setted.

Comment: Can you please use this for image and try again: `<img src="{{ URL::asset('images/td.jpg') }}" style="width:100%">` Make sure `td.jpg` image is in `images` folder!

Comment: Got it working now??

Comment: @HirenGohel I got this fixed by calling public path  and concatenating the image   Thank you so much for your valuable time

Comment: Ok, great! Is `URL::asset` works?

Comment: @HirenGohel actually it didn't work

Comment: Ok, no problem. Happy you've fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this fixed by calling public path and concatenating the image path to in my view as

```
{{public_path().'/images/td.jpg'}}
```

Thanks to all who was responding to my question

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by converting the image to base64. In my case I just used a converter that I found on google because my image was static but you can use this if you have to convert dynamically

```
$path = 'myfolder/myimage.png';
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
```

source: [How to convert an image to base64 encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967515/how-to-convert-an-image-to-base64-encoding)