# Is there way to insert an image (html) to PHPWord Template?

Tags: php, phpword

I get html body from tinymce that contains images and text (paragraph). But I get blank images when I'm trying to insert it to template.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fMRA.png)

There is my code:

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('./template.docx');

$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$content = '<p>Test</p> <img src="https://www.sciencemag.org/sites/default/files/styles/inline__450w__no_aspect/public/sparrow_16x9_0.jpg" />';
Html::addHtml($section, $content);

$xml = getXMLContent($section); 

\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setOutputEscapingEnabled(false);
$templateProcessor->setValue('test', $xml);
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setOutputEscapingEnabled(true);

$templateProcessor->saveAs('./result.docx');

function getXMLContent($section) {
    $xmlWriter = new XMLWriter(XMLWRITER::STORAGE_MEMORY, './', Settings::hasCompatibility());
    $containerWriter = new Container($xmlWriter, $section);
    $containerWriter->write();
    return $xmlWriter->getData();
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or there is an another way to do it?

Comment: Try to encode it in base64 format. See this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967515/how-to-convert-an-image-to-base64-encoding

Comment: Same result. :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all, which version of PHPWord are you using?
If you are using the latest version(as of Oct 2020), you can use this function:

https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates-processing.html#setimagevalue

Adding image to a Word template is as easy as:

`setImageValue(<tag>, <path to file>);`

I am currently trying to fix the height and width of the image, but I found it to be buggy, with the image width fixed at 3.04cm.

The API to insert image and setting it's height and width:

`setImageValue(<tag>, array('path'=><path to file>,'height'=><height>,'width'=><width>);`