# How to display image as base64_encocde in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I am storing the image path in my database table as

```
"uploads/flower.jpg".
```

Now I want to show the image in encrypted form like base64_encode.
I am using the below code

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;charset=utf8;base64,<?= base64_encode($eachproduct['prod_thumb']);?>"  alt="item" class="prodboximage">
```

However the image is not showing. How can I show that? Please help anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encoding the address is useless, but the image must be encoded.
You can use this https://elmah.io/tools/base64-image-encoder/ to encode your image and use the string that is generated there.

[image]

I encoded this image and received a string.And it works..

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
```

If you have more images or want to do this with PHP, [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967515/how-to-convert-an-image-to-base64-encoding)  will help you.

```
$path = "uploads/flower.jpg";
$info = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $info . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
```