# How to embed featured image to an email?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, contact-form-7

On a product page I have added a Contact Form 7 form that lets a visitor request more information about the product via email.

Now I want to embed the featured image (of the productpage the mail was sent from), in the email.

I'm using the plugin [Contact Form 7 - Dynamic Text Extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/) to use hidden fields in the contact form and some custom code that I found that retrieves the image. ([Original source](https://www.damiencarbery.com/2018/10/attach-woocommerce-product-image-to-contact-form-7-email/))

```
// Retrieve product featured imgae.
add_shortcode( 'product_img', 'dcwd_product_img_from_product_id' );
function dcwd_product_img_from_product_id() {
    $product_id = get_the_ID();
    $product_img = 'unknown';

    if ( is_int( $product_id ) ) {
        $product_img = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $product_id, 'thumbnail' );
    }
    return html_entity_decode( $product_img );
}
```

This code works, it gives the URL, but in the email it doesn't show the image when I put it in between tags.

I also tried:

```
$product_img = get_the_post_thumbnail( $product_id, 'thumbnail' );
```

This just displays the raw `<img />` html code.

There is a checkmark in the Contact Form 7 email settings that says: "Use HTML content type", this makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967515/how-to-convert-an-image-to-base64-encoding), I had to convert the image to base64.

This is the final code:

```
// Retrieve product featured imgae.
add_shortcode( 'product_img', 'dcwd_product_img_from_produt_id' );
function dcwd_product_img_from_produt_id() {
    $product_id = get_the_ID();
    $product_img = 'unknown';

    if ( is_int( $product_id ) ) {
        $product_img = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $product_id, 'large' );
    }

    $path = $product_img;
    $type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $data = file_get_contents($path);
    $base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);

    return html_entity_decode( $base64 );
}
```