# Compare two image for similarity or perfect match in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, image

I have an image that stored into my database & I need to build a function that give me true or false if the image that sent into the request is the same one or similar to that stored in my database?
I need to know if there any package in Laravel App or some way that help me with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood you need some request validation for process image and compare.this is not the good idea.but you can use:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.compareimages.php
i recommend you use it in queue

Comment: thanks for your advice but I need to know is this package work with Laravel 8?

Comment: yes.imagick is php extenstion and work with laravel 8

Answer (score 1):

I have had to do this in a project. Looks like you want to check for almost exact duplicates.
https://github.com/jenssegers/imagehash

Used it with Laravel really successfully. I had 40,000 or so images. You have to generate a hash of every image first.

```
    $photo = Photo::find($this->photo_id);
    $imageHash = new ImageHash;
    $hash =  $imageHash->hash($photo->path_thumb);
    $photo->comparison_hash = $hash;
    $photo->save();
    // then to compare 
    $imageHash = new ImageHash;

    $distance = $imageHash->distance($hash,$item->comparison_hash); //$item being another photo
    if($distance < $limit) {}//$limit being your similarity threshold
```

Answer (score 1):

For php 8.1 and higher and Laravel 8 and higher you can use https://github.com/sapientpro/image-comparator-laravel package. It has `Comparator` Facade that wraps main https://github.com/sapientpro/image-comparator class. For example:

```
use SapientPro\ImageComparatorLaravel\Facades\Comparator;

$similarity = Comparator::compare('path_to_image.jpg', 'path_to_image2.jpg');

echo $similarity; // 100.00
```

Answer (score -1):

Encode your image in base64 and compare with value in database. You don't need any package.

Comment: I think I've made my self clear up there I need to compare the (Content) not the title

Comment: I talk content not title. Check example below:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967515/how-to-convert-an-image-to-base64-encoding