# Trouble Displaying Images in PDF using Laravel-Dompdf: File Not Found or Unknown Type Issue

Tags: php, laravel, backend, laravel-dompdf

I make app to create pdf. Problem is that pdf doesn't display the image. For example I tryed add that in 2 ways:

```
<img src="http://localhost/images/pages/page-1.jpg">
<img src="{{asset('/images/pages/page-1.jpg')}}">
```

Urls is correct becouse in normal view img is display correctly. But if I tryed generate pdf via laravel-dompdf, it display me the error that file is  not found or type is unknown.
Controller's method is very simple

```
$data = $request->all();
$pdf = Pdf::loadView('pdf.simplepdf.layout', compact('data'));
return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
```

Do you know where my problem is?

Comment: The easiest way to incorporate images in DomPDF is to [base64 encode them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967515/how-to-convert-an-image-to-base64-encoding).